# Any way to save all *.psd layers separately

Tags: command-line, psd

Does one of you know, what is the best and most comfortable way to parse *.psd file **from command-line**, get all layers and save them all as, say, *.pngs? Preferably in MacOs, Linux or FreeBSD, but Windows is also OK.

Answer (score 11):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) will by default convert a psd to multiple images:

```
convert file.psd file.png
```

will result in file-0.png, file-1.png etc for each layer.  If you wanted a single image, use the `flatten` switch:

```
convert file.psd -flatten file.png
```

Imagemagick is available on osx, windows and linux.  And iOS somehow.

Comment: while this is true and convert indeed saves psd slides to images - just as it has been asked in the question (so I've upvoted) - in practice the actual output can be broken. For instance, you easily can get something like this - http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/9516/13172528.3/0_b371e_9abbaca4_orig

Comment: my png's are broken too, looks like imagemagick has problems to convert them from the psd with this simple line